# How to keep a log of user activity in an Android App?

Tags: android, mobile

I'm working on an Android App that needs to be tested to a select audience. During this testing period, we need to keep track of each session and store the user interactions somewhere to view later. Examples would be, the time at which a button was pushed or the touchscreen interactions. How would you guys suggest going about this?

Comment: https://github.com/ACRA/acra  ('nuff said)

Comment: You may use some real-time statistic analytics tools like Countly, Flurry. I use Countly which is also free and real-time.

Answer (score 6):

You should try Google Analytics for Android:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/

I use it on all my apps and games and I'm able to see which buttons are pressed, which screens are most visited, average score, where most people die during a level, etc...

Comment: if i understand correctly that will cover the in-app clicks and not outside the app . correct?

Comment: can we use it inside a background service like https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task